# C language, char=char with unexpected results

Tags: c, vector, matrix, codeblocks

Hi everybody and thanks in advance for any help, this is the situation:

```
#define N 12
[..]
char vect[N][2];
char strng[2];
[..]
vect[i][0]=strng[2]; //this two lines are in a simple for cycle 
vect[i][2]=strng[0];
```

Now, if in `string[2]` I have `"c 2"`, what I expect in `vect[i][0]` is `'2'` and in `vect[i][1]` `'c'`.

I use `code::blocks` and watching `vect` I have instead `"2@"`, but it could be `"2À"` as well.

Can you help me? Where am I wrong?

Comment: The reason the behavior is undefined is because while the index is out of bounds, there's probably something at that location in memory. You're getting SOMETHING but you'll never be able to tell what beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

Array indexes goes from zero up to the size *minus one*. So using e.g. `strng[2]` you access the *third* entry in the two-entry array. Accessing an array out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and the data will be indeterminate.

You should also remember that all strings in C are one more character than reported by e.g. [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), and that extra character is a special terminator character. So if you want a two-character string, you really need three characters: Two for the string, and one for the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite these statements

```
vect[i][0]=strng[2]; //this two lines are in a simple for cycle 
vect[i][2]=strng[0];
```

the following way

```
vect[i][0]=strng[1]; //this two lines are in a simple for cycle 
vect[i][1]=strng[0];
```

provided that string contains two characters { 'c', '2' }.

Take into account that array string can not have string literal `"c 2"`, because you defined it as

```
char strng[2];
```

that is it can contain only two characters.

If you want that the array would contain indeed `"c 2"` then you have to define it either as

```
char strng[3];
```

or as

```
char strng[4];
```

if you want to include the terminating zero.

In this case you may write

```
vect[i][0]=strng[2]; //this two lines are in a simple for cycle 
vect[i][1]=strng[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming strng literally contains "c 2", then your memory is the issue. strng[2] contains 3 cells iirc. 2 for holding chars and then a null terminator (ie \0). so when you try to access strng[2], (which you cant because you can only go to N-1 cells, where N is the number allocated for it) it contains undefined results, since it isnt null terminated and you are reaching beyond memory you allocated